# Video customview in full screen exits when toggling the device screen in android

Tags: android-webview, html5-video

I am developing an android application which is purely web based. It needs to display HTML5  based webpages using webview which is rich in multimedia contents. when I try to play video content embedded in the webpage its all gone fine and i am also able to play video in full screen.

But my main problem starts here: When I toggled the device screen while playing fullscreen video, it suddenly exits from playback to its current web page. I am stucked here and here I am including all codes that I used as I can in hopes someone can help me.

Activity that is used: MainActivity.java

`
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
private WebView webView;
private FrameLayout customViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
private View mCustomView;
private MyWebViewClient mWebViewClient;
private MyWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        mWebViewClient = new MyWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

        mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://yuotube.com");

}

public boolean inCustomView() {
    return (mCustomView != null);
}

public void hideCustomView() {
    mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    webView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    webView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    if (inCustomView()) {
        hideCustomView();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
            return true;
        }

        if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

// WebChromeClient Class  

public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    private Bitmap mDefaultVideoPoster;
    private View mVideoProgressView;


    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
       onShowCustomView(view, callback);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback) {

        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        mCustomView = view;
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customViewContainer.addView(view);
        customViewCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {

        if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
            mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_progress, null);
        }
        return mVideoProgressView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if (mCustomView == null)
            return;

        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Hide the custom view.
        mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Remove the custom view from its container.
        customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
        customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        mCustomView = null;
    }



}

// WebViewClient Class    
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient  {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
     ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", 
             "Loading multimedia! Please wait...", true);

       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        dialog.dismiss();
      }

    }
```

}

`web_activity.xml`

```
<!-- View that will be hidden when video goes fullscreen -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/nonVideoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <com.example.iptvmodified.VideoEnabledWebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>   



<!-- View where the video will be shown when video goes fullscreen -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- View that will be shown while the fullscreen video loads (maybe include a spinner and a "Loading..." message) -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/videoLoading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

I am searching for a solution for thisand googled this to death with no progress made. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when the device is rotated your activity gets destroyed and recreated. This is probably causing the WebView to get 'kicked out of' fullscreen playback.

You need to override Activity.onConfigurationChanged and declare you want to handle orientation changes in your manifest. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) for details.

Comment: I already did this. But it doesn't help. onHideCustomView() in WebChromeClient is still called.